# Url Scheme for ADVERTISING iOS 12.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I used:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=ADVERTISING"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

it worked on iOS `11.x` and before.
but with iOS `12.x` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple no longer allows `prefs:root=`](https://gist.github.com/deanlyoung/368e274945a6929e0ea77c4eca345560) via [section 2.5.1 in their guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements) (they now consider what you're doing a non-public URL scheme).

The best you can do is open up your app settings and the top level should be simple enough that the user can get to where they need from there.

Perhaps something like:

[`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationopensettingsurlstring?language=objc)